# Scipy-stats, how to make it faster/is it possible?

Tags: python

I'm currently using the following code:

```
prob = scipy.stats.norm(mu, np.sqrt(sigma)).pdf(o)  # korrekt
    return prob
```

I don't think there is much use for me to explain the variables, but mu is the expected values, sigma is my variance and o is an observation, and I want to find the probability of the given observation. It is working, but it is very slow since I call it a lot of times, and I got a lot faster result from just writing the normal distribution and attaining the probability from that.

## My question:

Is there a smarter way for me to call this function?

Comment: How are your multiple `o` observations stored?  If they are in a list then you could try using [list comprehension](https://www.pythonforbeginners.com/basics/list-comprehensions-in-python).

Comment: Is the mu and sigma constant for all observations?

Answer (score 1):

Two approaches...

**Vectorisation**

Takes advantage of the fact scipy/numpy perform calculations on arrays...

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.stats import norm

observations = np.random.rand(1000)
mu = np.mean(observations)
sigma = np.var(observations)
norm(mu, np.sqrt(sigma)).pdf(observations)
```

**List Comprehension**

This is a lot slower, but if your observations are in a list then you can...

```
list_of_observations = list(np.random.rand(1000))
mu = np.mean(list_of_observations)
sigma = np.var(list_of_observations)
prob = [norm(mu, np.sqrt(sigma)).pdf(o) for o in list_of_observations]
```

...but its easy to convert a list to an array and use the former solution as you can use [np.asarray()](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.asarray.html) to convert the list to an array...

```
norm(mu, np.sqrt(sigma)).pdf(np.asarray(list_of_observations))
```

Note also that if you are calculating the variance (`sigma`) yourself then rather than using `np.var()` you can get the standard deviation directly using `np.std()`.

Comment: Thank you for the response, I'll have to go for the last one, I'm not allowed to go for means in my solution, I'll try and see what I get!

Comment: I've clarified how you can go from a list to use the vectorised solution.  I'm afraid I don't understand what you mean by "*not allowed to go for means in my solution*".  I've purposefully calculated the mean and variance directly from the data itself only for illustrative purposes, if you already have these from some other data/parameters then you can use them.